# Odd results using FP package inside table environment

Tags: tables, tabu, fp

I'm trying to create a number of running totals using the [FP package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fp). I define a macro for adding numbers to a running total and then I define a macro to output the final value.

The problem I'm having is that I receive a different output from the totals macro depending on where I call it. If it's inside the table I receive the correct value however if it's outside then the value doubles.

Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{fp} 
\usepackage{tabu,longtable}

\FPset\totalone{0}
\FPset\totaltwo{0}

\def\add#1{%
  \FPadd\0\totalone{#1}
  \global\let\totalone\0
  \FPadd\0\totaltwo{#1}  
  \global\let\totaltwo\0
  #1
}

\def\ptotalone{%
  \totalone
  \FPset\0{0}\global\let\totalone\0
}

\def\ptotaltwo{%
  \totaltwo
  \FPset\0{0}\global\let\totaltwo\0
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{longtabu}{c}
      \add{0.25} \\
      \add{0.5}  \\
      \add{1}    \\
      total one: \ptotalone
    \end{longtabu}
  \end{table}
  total two: \ptotaltwo

\end{document}
```

Example output:

```
0.25
0.5
1
total one: 1.75
total two: 3.5
```

Comment: `longtabu` makes two passes over the tabular material.

Comment: I seem to get the same results with both tabu and longtabu so I guess this is common to both? If this is the case what would be the best way to only increment the total on a single pass?

Comment: Not using tabu.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm forced to use tabu to achieve the desired layout

Comment: Unfortunately you're out of luck. As far as I can tell, there's no conditional that's set when doing the last pass.

Answer (score 9):

`tabu` inherits some code from `tabularx` to disable `\write` during its trial runs, so you can just do your arithmetic on the final run when `\write` has its normal value.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{fp} 
\usepackage{tabu,longtable}

\FPset\totalone{0}
\FPset\totaltwo{0}
\let\origwrite\write

\def\add#1{%
\relax\ifx\origwrite\write
  \FPadd\0\totalone{#1}
  \global\let\totalone\0
  \FPadd\0\totaltwo{#1}  
  \global\let\totaltwo\0
\fi
  #1
}

\def\ptotalone{%
  \totalone
  \FPset\0{0}\global\let\totalone\0
}

\def\ptotaltwo{%
  \totaltwo
  \FPset\0{0}\global\let\totaltwo\0
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{longtabu}{c}
     \add{0.25} \\
      \add{0.5}  \\
      \add{1}    \\
      total one: \ptotalone
    \end{longtabu}
  \end{table}
  total two: \ptotaltwo

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, but I'd prefer that `tabularx` (and `tabu`) had a proper switch like `\ifmeasuring@` in `amsmath` for distinguishing between the two stages, rather than relying on `\ifx\origwrite\write`.

Comment: @egreg I could do something about one of those:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle any idea of how to adapt your trick to `tabularray` package? See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/674379/46718

Comment: tabularray  has added a command for this https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/179#issuecomment-1399695943  @Tobard

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This sounds very good! Don't know how to get such a recent package version but I will try this.

Answer (score 6):

The `tabu` (and so also `longtabu`) environments do two passes over the material, so your operations are performed twice. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to exist a conditional that's set in only one of the passes in order to do register settings or assignments only once (similar to `\ifmeasuring@` of `amsmath`).

So the answer seems to be: don't use `tabu`. Note that, as said by the author, the next version of `tabu` will *not* guarantee back compatibility, so I can't recommend using it (the author answered me saying, about back compatibility, "I don't care").