# FP calculation bug within tabularray

Tags: tables, calculations, tabularray, fp

Strange results had been reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95160/odd-results-using-fp-package-inside-table-environment/139441#139441) when using the `fp` package inside a table using `tabu` package.

[A solution had been proposed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139441/46718) to manage the fact that computations are done twice by performing a test on `\write` parameter.

As it comes to do similar calculations with `tabularray` I get odd results as well, despite the test. Any idea to fix this?
Here is a minimal example based on the topic I refer to:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{fp} 
\usepackage{tabu,longtable}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\FPset\totalone{0}
\FPset\totaltwo{0}
\let\origwrite\write

\def\add#1{%
\relax\ifx\origwrite\write
  \FPadd\0\totalone{#1}
  \global\let\totalone\0
  \FPadd\0\totaltwo{#1}  
  \global\let\totaltwo\0
\fi
  #1
}

\def\ptotalone{%
  \totalone
  \FPset\0{0}\global\let\totalone\0
}

\def\ptotaltwo{%
  \totaltwo
  \FPset\0{0}\global\let\totaltwo\0
}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{With longtabu:}

\begin{longtabu}{c}
    \add{0.25} \\
    \add{0.5}  \\
    \add{1}    \\
    total one: \ptotalone
\end{longtabu}

total two: \ptotaltwo

\subsection*{With tabularray:}

\begin{tblr}{c}
    \add{0.25} \\
    \add{0.5}  \\
    \add{1}    \\
    total one: \ptotalone
\end{tblr}

total two: \ptotaltwo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, `tblr` does four passes over the material.

Comment: But I don't understand why the condition on `\write` cannot prevent multicount.

Comment: @Tobard probably because `tblr` does not use the `\write` mechanism in the same way as `longtabu`. There may be other ways to test if you are in the final run though.

Comment: Hi @egreg , @Marijn : any clue of the kind of trick I can use here? I just have been through the whole `tabularray` source code and it seem opaque to me... :-(